# Need a query to do the table from two table with common and not common columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with multiples row. Table 1 has a few rows which Table 2 no has. And the opposite.

[image]

I need a query which will make a follow table from Table 1 and 2 and sort by ID. Rows Opt3 and Opt4 can be ignored. As below:

[image]

How to do a query with SELECT right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(SELECT Id, Question, Answer, Descr, Opt1, NULL AS Opt2
 FROM Table_1)
UNION
(SELECT Id, Question, Answer, Descr, NULL, Opt2
 FROM Table_2)
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: `Id` from both the table won't be in ascending order

Comment: @ErShakirAnsari that's what the `ORDER BY` is for, it applies to the result of the `UNION`. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html): "To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one."

Comment: Works. Thank you.